# Oracle sql developer save hebrew data - converted to gibberish

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, mybatis

I'm trying to insert hebrew content to table, using oracle sql developer db.
this is my code using myBatis:

```
<insert id="insertTaskTempImage" parameterType="com.ladpc.mobile.entities.TaskTempImage" useGeneratedKeys="false">

        INSERT INTO TASKS_TEMP_IMAGES (
        TASK_ID, 
        RASHUT_ID, 
        COMMENTS, 
        CREATION_DATE, 
        IMAGE,
        FILE_NAME 
        ) 
        VALUES (
        #{taskId,jdbcType=NUMERIC},
        #{rashutId,jdbcType=NUMERIC},
        #{comments, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{creationDate, jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
        #{image,jdbcType=BLOB},
        #{fileName,jdbcType=VARCHAR}


        )

    </insert>
```

After I insert the fileName to the table- with hebrew chars, I get gibberish  content in the table:
[image]

and when I load this content and show it in UI its writen in gibberish.
[image]
What need I do to resolve this issue?

edit:
My nls is on hebrew but its still not working...

[image]
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools > Preferences > Code Editor > Fonts.

Set it to something friendly like Tahoma.

Query your data, save it.

[image]

And then open said file.

[image]

Oracle SQL Developer is a java app - it's got full unicode supports out-of-the-box. Nine times out of 10, display issues are due to an incompatible font.

I don't read Hebrew, I used an ipsum generator for this text, so if it's offensive, my apologies.

Comment: sorry but its not working for me I still get gibberish chars after saving the data, In another tables its working fine, this  problem accured only on this specific table, maybe the reason is the  confusion   of two languages (filename(hebrew).jpg(english))...do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I think the problem is in my java insert code, when I'm adding Hebrew chars by sql developer editor its working fine,

Comment: your generator works well, there is not offensive words here :)

Answer (score 1):

[ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE](http://dba-oracle.com/bk_alter_session_set_nls_language.htm) . And you will have to find the right value for the language you want.

Comment: my nls is on hebrew and in another tables I got hebrew  chars well. this problem occured only on this specific table, do you have any idea about it?

Comment: this could happen if you inserted hebrew chars without nls_language hebrew

Comment: Edited my question with nls image, its on hebrew... but nothing

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I finded out the sulotion...
My client need to send this data in utf-8 encoding. 
The problem wasn't on server inserts, the server get this string on gibbresh...

Tanks for all answers!